# .NET Core solution projects and husky v6 installation

Tags: git, visual-studio, .net-core, husky, git-husky

I'd like to migrate husky from v4 to v6. As it says in the installation [guide](https://typicode.github.io/husky/#/?id=custom-directory):

> Another case you may be in is if your `package.json` file and `.git` directory are not at the same level. [...]
> By design, husky install must be run in the same directory as .git

So the problem is that in **.NET Core** solution I'm working on there's no `.git` folder anywhere to be found. I'm using **Visual Studio 2019** and all the git settings are available through the IDE.

Have anyone had this kind of problem or succeeded with husky v6 installation in similar circumstances?

I think that maybe it is possible to create `.git` directory in the solution's `Web project` and link it to the actual git settings location but I can't find anywhere where to find it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Visual Studio also creates `.git` folder in the root of the solution. Did you try to [show hidden files](https://www.technipages.com/show-hidden-files-windows)?

Comment: Yes @PriyankPanchal, you are right. After actually locating .git directory in the solution's root I followed husky's custom directory guide and Git hooks gets installed. Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0):

Your `.git` folder is probably hidden. There is no way for your VS git commands to work and not have a local .git folder in your repo folder.